# Set cookie in ReactApp with js-cookie does not recognizes expiration

Tags: reactjs, js-cookie

I am trying to set a cookie with an expiration of 10 days in a **React** app using **js-cookie**. I followed [this document](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions), but when I reload the page, the value of the cookie is `undefined` always. I expect it to keep the value I set for 10 days.

This is the code where I set the cookie:

```
handleClick() {
    const axios = require('axios');
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/api/login/',
      {
        username: 'admin@admin.com',
        password: 'Cancun10!',
        //username: this.state.email,
        //password: this.state.password.password,
      },
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      Cookies.set('x-xsrf-token', response.token, {expires: 10});
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

And this is the code where I get the value of the cookie:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    var csrfCookie = Cookies.get('x-xsrf-token')
    if(csrfCookie === 'undefined'){
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <LoginModal />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Albums />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

I expect the if to send to `LoginModal` the first time, but then to send to `Albums` every time after, for 10 days.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? a) not being able to set a specific expiration time, or  b) the cookies not being set at all?

Comment: Not to be able to set an expiration time.

Comment: What is the current value you are getting for expiration?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. The cookie is ok, but I was comparing the value of the cookie against `'undefined'`, but I have to compare it against `undefined`. As soon as I changed the condition like this: `if(csrfCookie === undefined)`, everything worked.